# ng-if does not work when placed outside of controller and $compile-ed with scope, but ng-show does

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile, angularjs-ng-if

I have a plain angular application which adds variables to the scope and simply display them. Which is simple and working.

But there is a part of the page that does not run in angular (practically it is a jQuery plugin), so I have to use `$compile` to enable directive usage in the rendered HTML. However, in this HTML, the `ng-if` directive does not work and always evaluates to false and disappeared. But when using `ng-show`, things are displayed/hidden as expected.

What could be the reason and how is a fix possible?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/kWp4CaED9ZFaOmY36ixT?p=preview

```
  <div ng-controller="GreeterController">
    <strong>$scope</strong><br>
    constTrue: {{constTrue}}<br>
    ng-if="constTrue": <span ng-if="constTrue">Yes</span><br>
    ng-show="constTrue": <span ng-show="constTrue">Yes</span><br>
    returnTrue(): {{returnTrue()}}<br>
    ng-if="returnTrue()": <span ng-if="returnTrue()">Yes</span><br>
    ng-show="returnTrue()": <span ng-show="returnTrue()">Yes</span><br>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div id="outsideController">
    <strong>$compile</strong><br>
    constTrue: {{constTrue}}<br>
    ng-if="constTrue": <span ng-if="constTrue">Yes</span><br>
    ng-show="constTrue": <span ng-show="constTrue">Yes</span><br>
    returnTrue(): {{returnTrue()}}<br>
    ng-if="returnTrue()": <span ng-if="returnTrue()">Yes</span><br>
    ng-show="returnTrue()": <span ng-show="returnTrue()">Yes</span><br>
  </div>
```

```js
app.controller('GreeterController', ['$scope', '$compile', '$timeout', function($scope, $compile, $timeout) {
  $scope.constTrue = true;
  $scope.returnTrue = function(){ return true }

  var outsideController = document.getElementById('outsideController');
  $compile(outsideController)($scope);
}]);
```

---

## RESULT

> ### $scope
>
> ```
> constTrue: true
> ng-if="constTrue": Yes
> ng-show="constTrue": Yes
> returnTrue(): true
> ng-if="returnTrue()": Yes
> ng-show="returnTrue()": Yes
> ```
>
> ### $compile
>
> ```
> constTrue: true
> ng-if="constTrue": 
> ng-show="constTrue": Yes
> returnTrue(): true
> ng-if="returnTrue()": 
> ng-show="returnTrue()": Yes
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because the element is being compiled twice. Once when the app bootstraps and again with the `$compile` service in the controller.

The solution is to declare to the AngularJS framework that the element not be compiled when bootstrapping.

Use the `ng-non-bindable` directive:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>
  <div id="outsideController">
    <strong>$compile</strong><br>
    constTrue: {{constTrue}}<br>
    ng-if="constTrue": <span ng-if="constTrue">Yes</span><br>
    ng-show="constTrue": <span ng-show="constTrue">Yes</span><br>
    returnTrue(): {{returnTrue()}}<br>
    ng-if="returnTrue()": <span ng-if="returnTrue()">Yes</span><br>
    ng-show="returnTrue()": <span ng-show="returnTrue()">Yes</span><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then when the controller compiles the element is will be clean and unmodified.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/EAaIoOg7FnpHjlUBjSgp?p=preview)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-non-bindable Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)